# or as procedure in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, macros, scheme, apply, variadic-functions

I want to apply `or` to every element of list, example:
`(apply or '(#t #t #f))` expected result `#t`, but I'm getting error:

> '#' to 'apply' has wrong type (kawa.lang.Macro) (expected: procedure, sequence, or other operator)

As I understand `or` is not a procedure.
**Is there any procedure that can be used instead of `or`?**

Comment: You could define your own procedure that uses `or`.

Comment: How do you get from "applying or to every element" of `'(#t #t #f)`  to the result of `#t`?

Comment: `(or #t #t #f)` is the same as `true or true or false` and it is ture

Comment: So as @ScottHunter said I did write own procedure and it worked, `(define (orp . ls) (if (< (length ls) 2) (car ls) (or (car ls) (orp (cdr ls)))))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `exists`*. Whenever you would use `(apply or some-list)`, you can use `(exists values some-list)`. Or if you like, you can define a function that uses `exists` to do that:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs lists))

(define (or* . lst)
  (exists values lst))
```

`values` is the identity function, so `(values x)` is just `x`.

`exists` is a higher-order function defined so that `(exists f (list x ...))` is equivalent to `(or (f x) ...)`.

For example `(exists values (list #t #t #f))` is equivalent to `(or (values #t) (values #t) (values #f))`, which is the same as `(or #t #t #f)`.

Trying it out:

```
> (apply or* '(#t #t #f))
#t
> (apply or* '(#f #f #f))
#f
> (or* #t #t #f)
#t
> (or*)
#f
```

*`exists` is sometimes known as `ormap` or `any`

Comment: That's Racket-specific but the question isn't tagged <racket>.

Comment: Could you explain your approach, I can't read the code, and I'm getting warnings when trying to execute it.

Comment: Scheme doesn't have `ormap`

Comment: Is it called `any` or `exists` or something then?

Comment: Could you edit you code so that it fully works so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I have edited it to use `exists`, which is proper R6RS.

Answer (score 5):

In [SRFI-1 List Library](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) you have `every` and `any` which basically is `and` and `or` for a procedure over a list.

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base)
        (only (srfi :1) every any)

(define num1-10 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(define odd1-9 '(1 3 5 7 9))

(every odd? num1-10) ; ==> #f
(any odd? num1-10)   ; ==> #t
(every odd? odd1-9)  ; ==> #t
```

For a list of booleans the procedure only need to return the argument. `values` returns it's argument and serve as identity:

```
(define booleans '(#f #t))
(every values booleans) ; ==> #f
(any values booleans)   ; ==> #t
```

SRFI-1 is a safe choice as it is the list library of the upcoming R7RS Red edition. In many R5RS and R6RS implementations SRFI-1 is included and you can easily add it from the SRFI reference implementation if it isn't. In DrRacket's default language DrRacket, that has `ormap` and `andmap`, you can opt to use SRFI-1 instead by importing them with `(require srfi/1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own procedure that uses or

```
(define (orp . ls) 
     (if (null? ls) #f
           (if (< (length ls) 2) (car ls) (or (car ls) (orp (cdr ls))))))
```

And use it:

```
(apply orp '(#t #f #t))
```

Comment: `> (orp)
. . car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '()`

Comment: Could you show me how to use it in some context? I can't read this code.

Comment: Just run it without arguments: `(or)` yields `#f`, whereas `(orp)` throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that `or` (and `if`, `cond`, `and`  ....) operator has [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) semantics. Hence `(or #t (/ 1 0))` does not make a division by zero. Because of that `or`  cannot be an ordinary function.

You might code a lambda to force the eager evaluation, e.g. define your `eager-or` variadic function, and apply that.